# Adjust div width by amount of internal list elements

Tags: css, navigation, css-float, html-lists

I have a type of navigation that is contained within a '`pill`' of sorts.

I need the `pill` (surrounding container) to automatically resize based on the amount of elements in the navigation.

I have the `pill` container centered on the page, so I don't think a `float: left;` or `float: right;` will work because it will override the `margin: 0 auto;`.

Here is a fiddle with an example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/TylerB/EU6XG/1/

How can I set this div element's width based on the amount of navigation items in the list?

Comment: Do you still want the line to break when it reaches 100%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `display: table`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/EU6XG/6/

```
.tabset-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
}
```

Also add `overflow: hidden` to the tabs so then your rounded corners still show

```
.tabset {
        overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going in jQuery direction - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EU6XG/7/) (get the width and pass it trough `.css()`)
+ `display: inline-block` on `.tabset`

Comment: If I don't have to use jQuery, I don't want to.